# i want to stored all the rawmaterialSchema in UsersSchema using objectId

Tags: mern

the code follows two Schemas one is userSchema and another is rawMaterialSchema i want to refrence rawmaterialSchema in userSchema using ObjectId

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
     const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;
    
    const rawmaterialSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true, 
            trim: true,
            maxlength: 32,
            Unique: true
        },
        size: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            trim: true,
            maxlength: 32
        },
        partyname: {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            maxlength: 40,
            required: true
        },
        partyphonenumber: {
            type: Number,
            maxlength: 10,
            trim: true
        },
        user: {
            type: ObjectId,
            ref: "User",
            required: true
       }
    }, { timestamps: true });
    
    module.exports = mongoose.model('Rawmaterial', rawmaterialSchema)
```

Comment: Can you please add some info about your task and desired behaviour?

Comment: i have created a rawmaterialSchema and i want to refer that in userSchema. like whenever something is comes in rawmaterialSchema i want to store it in rawmaterialSchema

Comment: can you add all these info to the question via "Edit" btn :)

Comment: i have corrected my question

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you can do it this way

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
 const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;

const rawmaterialSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, //<----- CHANGED
        ref: 'users' //<----- CHANGED
    },
    size: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        maxlength: 32
    },
    partyname: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        maxlength: 40,
        required: true
    },
    partyphonenumber: {
        type: Number,
        maxlength: 10,
        trim: true
    },
    user: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
        required: true
   }
}, { timestamps: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Rawmaterial', rawmaterialSchema)
```

Assuming that you have userSchema with name `user`

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    ...
  },
  ...
  
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
```